# Dynamic programming with matrix multiplication

Tags: algorithm

q = cost/scalar multiplications
q = m[i,k] + m[k+1,j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];

suppose A is a 10 × 30 matrix, B is a 30 × 5 matrix, and C is a 5 × 60 matrix. Then,

(AB)C = (10×30×5) + (10×5×60) = 1500 + 3000 = 4500 operations
A(BC) = (30×5×60) + (10×30×60) = 9000 + 18000 = 27000 operations.

Why (p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j] ) is required ?

Answer (score 0):

`m[i, k]` gives us the cost of multiplying all matrices from the `[i, k]` range. `m[k + 1, j]` gives the cost of multiplying all matrices from the `[k + 1, j]` range. After working with these two subranges, we have two matrices remaining(one as a result of multiplication of the first range and the other as the result of multiplication of the second). So we need to add the cost of multiplying them to the answer.

Comment: In above example, i have used only m[i,k] + m[k+1,j] not (p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j] ) kraskevich

Comment: @chirag You haven't used `m[i, k]` or `m[k + 1, j]` there at all. You simply computed the cost of multiplying `A` by `B` and then the cost of multiplying `(A*B)` and `C`.